# Dynamic gulp.dest path for modular app

Tags: module, gulp, gulp-rename, gulp-task

I'm trying to setup gulp for a modular application. In my public folder, I have modules each with their own `src/sass` and `dist/css` folders. I want to transform and transfer the sass files from `src/sass` to their respective `dist/css` folder. There could also be more folders under `src/sass` like `src/sass/admin` and `src/sass/user` with .scss in them. These folder structure should also be replicated in the `dist/css` like so: `dist/css/admin` and `dist/css/user`. These additional folders depends on the modules.

The problem is that the Modules could be removed and added so I don't want reference the module name directly in the `gulp.dest` path. I need it to be dynamic depending on the `gulp.src` path.

Let's say I have a folder structure as shown below.

```
public
    |-- Modules
        |-- Module1
        |   |-- dist
        |   |   |-- css
        |   |   |   |-- style.css
        |   |-- src
        |       |-- sass
        |           |-- style.scss
        |-- Module2
        |   |-- dist
        |   |   |-- css
        |   |       |-- admin
        |   |       |   |-- style.css
        |   |       |-- user
        |   |           |-- style.css
        |   |-- src
        |       |-- sass
        |           |-- admin
        |           |   |-- style.scss
        |           |-- user
        |               |-- style.scss
        |-- Module3
            |-- dist
            |   |-- css
            |       |-- style.css
            |-- src
                |-- sass
                    |-- style.scss
```

Here are the gulp tasks I've tried.

### 1. Using path.join

```
gulp.task('sass-modules', function () {
    gulp.src('public/Modules/**/src/sass/**/style.scss', {base: "./"})
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file) {
        return path.join(path.dirname(file.path), '???/dist/css');
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

### 2. Using rename

```
gulp.task('sass-modules', function () {
    gulp.src('public/Modules/**/src/sass/**/style.scss', {base: "./"})
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.dirname += "???/dist/css";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

I'm not sure what to write instead of the "???". I've tried multiple variant like `'../../../dist/css'` and it all seems to try and transfer my css files to something like `public/Modules/Module1/dist/css/Module1/src/sass` or `dist/public/...` Nothing has worked so far.

I've checked through StackOverflow before posting this and I couldn't find exactly what I need.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I fixed it, I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!
I would still like to know if this is considered a good solution?

```
.pipe(rename(function (path) {
    path.dirname = path.dirname.replace('src', 'dist').replace('sass', 'css');
}))
```

Comment: you can try use gulp using the base option 

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase